# resize image to fixed s size and maintaining the original image size

Tags: php

I want to create a thumbnail from user uploaded image with fixed size (400*320)
saved in thumbnails folder and copy of the original image is sent to uploads folder when the user click the thumbnail. The original image appears but the problem with the code that the original image uploaded is the same size of thumbnail please any solution?

Here is the code:

```
function ak_img_resize($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext) {
    list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);

    $img = "";
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    if ($ext == "gif"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefromgif($target);
    } else if($ext =="png"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
    } else { 
      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    }
    $w = 400;
    $h = 320;
    $tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    // imagecopyresampled(dst_img, src_img, dst_x, dst_y, src_x, src_y, dst_w, dst_h, src_w, src_h)
    imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_orig, $h_orig);
    imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 90);
```

Comment: i send the code that upload image and using resize_img.php file. please do it for me iam not developer i need to take the code from  you and paste it

Comment: thanks very much .code worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are putting the original through this function, and maybe that is because you are trying to compress it or whatever, but if you want the original to stay its original size, just move the uploaded file to where it has to go first, then on success of that file being moved, make a thumbnail copy from that moved file.

If you want to put the original image file through your function, to scale-back the quality or whatever, try making these adjustments:

```
# Notice the re-organizing of the params--------vv----------vv
function ak_img_resize($target, $newcopy, $ext, $w = false, $h = false)
    {
        list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);
        # If you keep the width empty, take original size
        if(empty($w))
          $w    =   $w_orig;
        # If you keep the height empty, take original size
        if(empty($h))
          $h    =   $h_orig;

        $img = "";
        $ext = strtolower($ext);
        if ($ext == "gif"){ 
          $img = imagecreatefromgif($target);
        } else if($ext =="png"){ 
          $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
        } else { 
          $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
        }
        $tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
        // imagecopyresampled(dst_img, src_img, dst_x, dst_y, src_x, src_y, dst_w, dst_h, src_w, src_h)
        imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_orig, $h_orig);
        imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 90);
    }
```

**To use:**

```
#Sized down:
ak_img_resize($target,$newcopy,$ext,400,320);

#Original:
ak_img_resize($target,$newcopy,$ext);
```